# Добавление символа к строке в C без библиотек

Tags: c

Всем привет. Допустим есть строка `”Hello World”`. Можно ли добавить в конец строки символ `!` без использования библиотек и как это сделать.
Я только начинаю изучать этот язык. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если там есть место для этого символа...

Comment: Создать строку на 1 символ больше. Скопировать туда предыдущую строку. Дописать в конце нужный символ. Как-то так

Comment: Эта строка физически находится в области памяти программы с флагом ReadOnly. Трогать её нельзя, прога упадёт. Вы можете создать новую строку где-нибудь. А там делайте, что хотите.

Comment: в Си нет строк... от этого у Вас и проблемы. Читайте про realloc и memcpy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// gcc -Wall -std=c11 -Os stradd.c -o stradd
# include <stdio.h>
char  const hw [ ] = "Hello, world"  ;
char  const ac [ ] = "!" ;
int main  ( ) {
  char  result [ sizeof  ( hw  ) + sizeof  ( ac  ) - 1 ] ;
  char  * j = & ( result [ 0 ] ) ;
  char  const * i = & ( hw [ 0 ] ) ;
  // копируем строку до символа конца строки '\00'
  do  {
    ( * j ) = ( * i ) ;
    ++  i ;
    ++  j ;
  } while ( * i ) ;
  i = & ( ac [ 0 ] ) ;
  // затем продолжаем копировать дальше другую строку
  do  {
    ( * j ) = ( * i ) ;
    ++  i ;
    ++  j ;
  } while ( * i ) ;
  // ставим конец строки сами
  ( * j ) = '\00' ;
  printf("\"%s\" + \"%s\" = \"%s\"\n",hw,ac,result); }
```

результат :

```
> ./stradd 
"Hello, world" + "!" = "Hello, world!"
```

Comment: Идеоматичное копирование строки на Си пишется так  -- `while (*dst++ = *src++);`  (одна простая строчка, после нее указатель `dst` смотрит сразу за терминирующий 0)

Comment: Ваше предложение это очень плохой стиль. Четыре команды в одной строке. Не определённость в инкрементировании указателей. Непонятно что выполниться перед чем. Присваивание в вашем предложении это самих указателей!! @avp

Comment: И тем не менее, это было заложено авторами в язык с самого его рождения (лет 50 назад) и до сих пор у всех *нормальных* людей работает и удивления не вызывает. Впрочем, о вкусах не  спорят

Comment: Я проверил в ассемблере и удивился как так... Но если инкременты записать во внутрь тела while ничего не изменилось. Я уж лучше прибавлять буду там. @avp